# Django: split forms.py in several files

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a very long forms.py and I'd like to split it to smaller parts with as few as possible changes in the code.

Any ideas?

Comment: What specifically are you having problems with? Why is this difficult?

Comment: The answer says it's apparently simple. I know that splitting views.py can be little bit messy so I asked because I didn't know if there is any catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason that we put Django form classes into a `forms.py` file is convention. It makes it easy for others to look at your application and know what kinds of things he or she will find in any given file. It's good to follow conventions, but it's not the law and you're free to organize your code as you please.

Here's what I'd do:

First of all, see if you can reduce the amount of code by factoring out duplicated code. Common validation logic could be pulled into [custom validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#using-validators). Forms that share fields or functionality could inherit from a common parent.

If you have created custom field classes, you could separate all those into a file called something like `formfields.py` in the application directory, and simply import them into `forms.py`. Likewise, if you have custom validators, you can take those out and import them.

If none of that reduces filesize enough for you, I would split up my form classes by function into several files, e.g. `forms_user.py`, `forms_products.py`, `forms_data_entry.py` or whatever. That way, it's still obvious what we will find in a given file. You will have to change import statements wherever your old forms are referenced, but those should be the only changes necessary.

Comment: This is a good idea. I'm thinking on this right now. One thought I had was to have a `forms.py` in each module but this seems counter-Django-ish, so I'm thinking of using these other ideas...

Answer (score 8):

I can't comment, so I'm writing answer. The other thing you can do is to create a `forms`
 directory(remember about `__init__.py`) in an app directory and split your forms to formone.py, form2.py,...

Then you can import form like that `from myapp.forms.formone import FormOne`

Or in the `__init__.py` you can place code:

```
from formone import *
from form2 import *
```

And you can import forms with `from myapp.forms import FormOne`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to make as few changes as possible, splitting forms.py into multiple files by function (forms_user.py, forms_product.py) is the easiest.

If you have time to refactor or are starting a new project, the best solution is to make a new django app for each component of your project (e.g. users, projects...) each with its own forms.py file. If a single django app gets too big lots of things stop scaling (models.py, views.py etc.) and maintenance gets harder across the board.